# Why do we need $\sigma$-algebra in the definition of a measurable space?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, definition, lebesgue-measure

A measurable space is a triple $(M, \Sigma, \mu)$.

I am confused by one thing, to my knowledge almost everything you think of is measurable. So why do we need $\Sigma$? Why is that a measurable set is an element of the sigma algebra instead of the whole space?

In other words, take $M = \mathbb{R}^2$. Draw a star. That's measurable. Draw a curve. That's measurable. Draw a dot. That's measurable. Draw a giraffe. That's measurable.

Take arbitrary union of open sets, that is an open set, which is measurable. Take arbitrary intersection of open sets, that may not be an open set, in fact it could be a dot, but a dot is still measurable. Same with closed sets. If it comes out to be an empty set, no worries, that is also measurable. Take the whole space to be the real line, that measure is infinity, still measurable.

So why don't we just write $(M, \mu)$ instead of $(M, \Sigma, \mu)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you allow the axiom of choice, then there are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are not Lebesgue measurable.

More generally, $\sigma$-algebras can be useful ways of keeping track of information. This is often the case when studying stochastic processes, for example.

Comment: Hi what are these subsets of $\mathbb{R}$? I am thinking really hard to come up with one.

Comment: You can't really write them down. Google for Vitali set.

Comment: @menag Why is it so hard to write them down? Just use a pencil

Comment: Read the wikipedia article about vitali sets. The problem is, that you need the axiom of choice to get the set.

Comment: Nonmeasurable subsets of ${\mathbb R}$ are not that important here. But your second point is essential. Taking care of the underlying $\sigma$-field ${\cal F}$ allows to enlarge it in the course of the argument. For example when studying weather you might first argue just about temperature. Taking moisture into account as well allows of a much finer taxonomy of states.

Comment: @Christian Blatter: I think that non-measurable sets were important to mention, because the OP was under the impression that every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable.